# AC on 12 Fusion

Tags: heater-blower

I'm currently having issue where my ac unit will turn off and back on. My idea was going towards a shortage in the blower motor wire because when I move it around the unit turns on. I've had this issue for over a year. It also happens with the heating also. That's why my mind is saying a wire issue. Can anyone help me? If it is a wiring issue will I still have to replace the entire blower motor?

Answer (score 2):

If you can move the wiring and the blower motor turns on disconnect the connector and look for proper fit, burned wires, loose terminals etc... It may just need a new harness connector. If the wiring is burned replace the blower motor as well as the connector.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I looked for bad wiring before but it seems to be in good condition. I also tested the connection from the blower motor itself to see if it's getting fire to it, just as well as the fuses. I have yet to check the end that the harness connects to. I some how left that out lol. Thanks again